# allocator as default argument in vector and list

Tags: c++, stl

When I try to use sequential containers like vector, list, it shows second default argument as,

```
typename _Ax = allocator <_Ty> >
```

I am curious to know why it is needed in other sequential containers but not in queue. What is exact purpose of this.

Best Regards

Comment: `std::queue` is not a container, it is a container *adapter*.

Comment: @AndyProwl Should be an answer.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I'm getting lazy :)

Comment: @AndyProwl 'bout time you gave everyone else a chance to answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::queue` (like `std::priority_queue` and `std::stack`) is a *container adapter*, rather than a container. One of the template arguments it takes is a container:

```
template<
     class T,
     class Container = std::deque<T>
  > class queue;
```

The queue uses that container internally – it's basically a wrapper around the container, providing a queue-like interface.

The container (which is a `std::deque` by default) of course has an allocator parameter, and because the queue is just a wrapper, it obviously uses the same allocator as the container. So the allocator parameter of the queue is implicit in its container parameter.

The *purpose* of the allocator parameter is to enable the user to define methods of memory allocation/deallocation (as well as, sometimes, methods of construction/destruction) that are optimized for the use case at hand. The standard allocator will essentially perform `malloc` and `free` (or something equivalent) whenever allocation and deallocation is required, which may be undesirable in certain scenarios. Passing it a customized allocator (e.g. the [Boost pool allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html)) may improve efficiency, or be otherwise useful.

Comment: The allocator is also used for construction/destruction of elements, so can be used to customise that (à la "uses-allocator construction" and `scoped_allocator_adaptor`) as well as control memory allocation.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Right, construction/destruction too. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Allocators handle all the requests for allocation and deallocation of memory for a given container like `std::vector`.

`std::queue` is not a container, it is a container adapter, acts as a wrapper to the underlying container. So it doesn't need an allocator, only the underlying container requires one.

```
template<class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> class queue;
```

`std::stack` and `std::priority_queue` are other container adapters

Comment: +1 I like your answer too. But I have to chose one, so chosen another one.